# How do I Specify PDF Output Path in Chrome Headless Mode

Tags: pdf, google-chrome-headless

[This page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome#create_a_pdf_dom) shows that you can now use chrome to generate a PDF of a webpage using the following CLI command:

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf https://www.chromestatus.com/
```

However, it does not state how to specify the output path.

How do you specify the output path?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf="C:/temp/pdftest.pdf" https://www.google.com/
```

source:

[image]

https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/headless/app/headless_shell.cc?type=cs&l=63