# Chrome headless in Ubuntu

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, pdf, headless

I'm trying to use chrome headless print to pdf option to print some pdf Files in ubuntu and here's my command line :

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf  http://www.google.com
```

Now if I ran it like that it runs perfecly and the file is generated.

***BUT*** when I add the name of the file after --print-to-pdf :

```
google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf gen.pdf http://www.google.com
```

an error occur :

```
[1213/020159.194304:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(605)] Open multiple tabs is only supported when remote debugging is enabled.
```

Any solution to this ? thx.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing an `=` between `--print-to-pdf` and `gen.pdf`.

This should work:

`google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=gen.pdf http://www.google.com`

Similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44681065/how-do-i-specify-pdf-output-path-in-chrome-headless-mode)

Comment: that did the trick. I'll accept your answer shortly, Just a notice : In windows it runs without `=`.

Comment: In my case it is not working even after adding = in cent OS 7.

Comment: In my case, I was adding a space where I didn't mean to.